# Make div full width of screen, but show page scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my site, I have a topBar. I want this to be full screen, but I want the vertical page scrollbar to be shown, like the header for StackOverflow.

My css is:

```
#topBar
{
    background: black
    color: #fff;
    height: 60px;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `width:100vw;`?

Comment: just did..it did not help...

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle for an example of your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by full screen? The entire width and height of the viewport?

Answer (score 1):

Did you override the body's initial margin values?

Also, to force show a vertical scroll bar, you can do:

`overflow-y: scroll;`